# Google Fusion Table Last Modified Date

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api, google-fusion-tables

I'm using a fusion table as a source for map data and wanted to include the last modified date of the fusion table below the map.  Can anyone share javascript code to do that?  I looked at the Google docs API and found a reference to an edited-max property but couldn't figure out how to make that work with a fusion table.

Answer (score 0):

I rely on the undocumented, but so far very reliable Fusion Table JSONP interface to retrieve data values from Fusion Tables in conjunction with the Google Maps API for display.  The problem is that you can only retrieve the FT values via the Maps API on certain layer click events, e.g. to display an infoWindow.  I recently posted some code demonstrating the JSONP approach which could be modified to get execute **"SELECT MAXIMUM(modified_date) from NNNNN"**

[See the example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533602/text-search-autocomplete)

I just tested this on my table and it worked.  The only requirement is to ensure your column is of type datetime.